# Cleric build to maximize melee damage and spell healing

Tags: spells, feats, skills, cleric, pathfinder-2e

I am making a Dwarf Warpriest Cleric of Shelyn wielding a Glaive. I expect to use Medium armor. I am planning this character out through level 20.

I'm looking for a build of feats, skills (if applicable) and spells that maximize my damage in melee and healing with spells. Other character choices are locked in.

If it matters, my allies in this group are: rogue, sorcerer, barbarian, monk, and fighter(longbow).

My original plan includes:

- [Domain Initiate](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=265) (Zeal Domain)
- [Communal Healing](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=271)
- [Divine Weapon](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=282)

What Feats, Skills, and Spells (through level 20) will allow this character to do its highest DPR with a glaive and heal the most with its spell slots?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: What level is this character? How do you define "good" in the different categories? If you want to "master a craft", you could take e.g. Smithing Lore instead of Crafting. Is that an option?

Comment: It may become important to know that this question may be "Closed" until you add more details. We need specific criteria to help you (as opposed to the collection of opinions you would get on a forum). This is more of an "on hold" status; if you add more details we can open it back up and attempt to give you the best answer we can.

Comment: If you would *rather* collect a bunch of opinions by not adding too much detail, a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) might be better for you.

Comment: I don't want an opinion, i want the numbers maximized

Comment: So, if I'm reading this right, your goal is the highest amount of damage and healing for a Dwarf Warpriest Cleric wielding a Glaive at the cost of everything else (spells per day, variety of spells, non-combat abilities, defenses/survivability, etc)?

Comment: Also, is that damage and healing per round or Action? Do you want to alternate healing a round and damage a round, or do you need to do both in one round? Do you care who you're healing (yourself, close allies, far allies) or does it not matter as long as the number is high?

Comment: The rounds can be specialized. The healing should be allies, but can be restricted to just close allies.

Comment: I voted to re-open. Thanks for the edits, this looks great! I'm writing an answer, but you may want to know that Shelyn doesn't have the Zeal domain, which may influence your thinking outside of StackExchange.

Comment: @indigochild Thank you for the heads-up

Comment: This technically is not an answer, but may end up making a bigger difference to your dps than actual answers: Make sure some of your companions pick up the medicine skill, and ideally invest feats in it (particularly the feat that allows for combat healing). It will lighten the load on you to be the party healer considerably, while also increasing the party's ability to survive. Which in turn, will let you spend more of your actions on dps.

Comment: As an addendum - the medicine skill is good enough that a party with no 'healing classes' can have sufficient healing (Though you would want more than one character with it).

Comment: Also, as a more general piece of advice: debuffs and action economy are often worth more than simple dps in PF2e. E.g. if you can spend less than a third of your party's collective actions to remove a third of your opponent's actions, then you have profited considerably (vs bosses it is actually better than this, but is hard to explain in a few lines of unformatted text; but the jist of it is that generally higher level creatures' actions are worth more than yours, for multiple reasons) - and similarly reduced the amount of healing your party will have to do overall.

Comment: I suppose that's all good to note, but the question isn't about the "most effective" Warpriest build (as I suspect it would be better off Cloistered Cleric to capitalize on CC and similar spells). OP asked about doing high damage and healing. Some people have more fun counting up big numbers than actually being the most effective they "could be" in a system where you don't always have to be. (I do like spreading the good word of intent relating to Medicine being able to replace a dedicated healer, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Vitals @ L20

**Name**: Droshgar the Beautiful (or pick your own, probably)
**Ancestry and Heritage**: [Dwarf](https://2e.aonprd.com/Heritages.aspx?Ancestry=1) (any; recommended Ancient-Blooded or Anvil)
**Background**: Flexible; anything that allows Strength or Wisdom (recommended [Scholar](https://2e.aonprd.com/Backgrounds.aspx?ID=36))
**Class**: [Warpriest](https://2e.aonprd.com/Doctrines.aspx?ID=3) doctrine [Cleric](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=5) 20 (**DC** 42)
**STR** 24 (22+Apex); **DEX** 12; **CON** 20; **INT** 12; **WIS** 22; **CHA** 18
**HP** 210; **AC** 42; **Fort** +34m*; **Ref** +28e; **Will** +35m*
*Rolling a success on a Fort or Will Save results in a Critical Success

### Class Feats

\begin{array}{l|l|l}
\text{Level} & \text{Feat} & \text{Benefit} \\
\hline
1 & \text{Domain Initiate} & \text{mandatory} \\
2 & \text{Healing Hands} & \text{~+1 healed per die} \\
4 & \text{Communal Healing} & \text{Heal self = spell level} \\
6 & \text{Divine Weapon} & \text{situational +1d4 or 1d6 damage} \\
8 & \text{Emblazon Armament} & \text{+1 damage} \\
10 & \text{Replenishment of War} & \text{temp hp for using your glaive} \\
12 & \text{Shared Replenishment} & \text{allies get temp hp for you using your glaive} \\
14 & \text{Emblazon Energy} & \text{+1d4 energy damage} \\
16 & \text{Align Armament} & \text{+1d6 alignment damage for 1 turn} \\
16 alt & \text{Channel Smite} & \text{add Harm to weapon attack} \\
18 & \text{Extend Armament} & \text{Alignment lasts 1 minute} \\
18 alt & \text{Echoing Channel} & \text{can Heal or Harm 2 adjacent targets for more} \\
20 & \text{Maker of Miracles} & \text{extra 10th level spell slot*} \\
20 alt & \text{Metamagic Channel} & \text{Echoing Channel (or Heroic Recovery) does not cost an action} \\
\end{array}

*This is probably a 2nd casting of [Avatar](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=16)

Note: Alternative 20 should only be taken if you take alt 18. Otherwise they are not necessarily linked.

### Class Feats (Honorable Mentions)

- Improved Communal Healing (choose another to heal with the ability)
- Advanced Domain
- Heroic Recovery (bonuses to single-target Heal)
- Fast Channel (reduce actions for AoE heal to 2)

### Ancestry Feats (relevant only)

- (1) Vengeful Hatred (+weapon dice damage, situational)

### General/Skill Feats

There are no General or Skill feats that affect your weapon damage or healing. You could specialize in Medicine to reduce the need for spells between battles, and/or Athletics to enable you to shove, trip, and disarm better. You will probably want Incredible Initiative and Fleet, as they present ancillary benefits to you.

---

Your melee with a basic +3 m.s. glaive will look like:

- - **Melee** speed glaive +34 (deadly 3d8, forceful, reach), **Damage** 4d8+10 slashing plus 1d6 good, 1d4 (cold or electricity) and 1d4 force or 1d6 good if you've cast a spell this round

---

Desirable Equipment

- +3 Major Striking Glaive (Speed, Greater Corrosive, Greater Flaming)

  - Speed makes it far easier to to activate your Divine Weapon ability because you have one less action "spent" on attacking
- +3 Major Striking Glaive (Dancing, Greater Corrosive, Greater Flaming)

  - This is obviously optional but I figured I'd include it for completeness.
- +3 Major Resilient Breastplate
- Belt of Giant Strength
- Greater Healer's Gloves (not really spells but worth noting)
- Greater Boots of Bounding (again not directly relevant, but useful for melee)

Using this equipment, your attack would look something like this.

- **Melee** speed glaive +34 (deadly 3d8, forceful, reach, critical 2d10 persistent fire, critical 6d6 shield/armor damage), **Damage** 4d8+10 slashing plus 1d6 good, 1d6 fire (ignored Resist), 1d6 acid (ignored resist), 1d4 (cold or electricity) and 1d4 force or 1d6 good if you've cast a spell this round
- **Melee** dancing glaive +25 (deadly 3d8, forceful, reach, critical 2d10 persistent fire, critical 6d6 shield/armor damage), **Damage** 4d8+3 slashing plus 1d6 good, 1d6 fire (ignored Resist), 1d6 acid (ignored resist)